# how to write a batch (windows) to start Cygwin (mintty.exe) and then execute a python script?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cygwin

Pretty much as titled. If I were to manually do this, I would first open a Cygwin Terminal (which should be /cygwin/bin/mintty.exe), and then in that terminal, cd to the directory that has the python script, and then execute the python script by doing "python myPython.py". I'm wondering if I can write a batch script or a bash script to do this: start a Cygwin Terminal, cd to a directory, execute a python script in the directory. 
Thanks.

Edited:
So I have a python script that generates csv files for activities through mongodb.This script won't function if I run it through windows cmd. I have to run it in cygwin terminal (mintty.exe). So any alternatives to execute the python script won't work. I have to somehow start a Cygwin Terminal and execute the python script through there. Any ideas please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of your needs it could be better to start mintty (creating a new window) instead of starting bash inside the cmd.exe window.

When you want to use ansi escape sequences then it works better with a real mintty window, as the cmd window ignores the escape sequences for window resizing and positioning.

```
start "" C:\cygwin\bin\mintty --exec ./myProgramToExecute.sh
```

Comment: I tried this. I noticed that if I execute the command 'start "" C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe', I will start a new window. However, the return value from sys.platform is still "win32". Is there any to start the mintty.exe in windows cmd and get a new window which is under platform "cygwin"?

Comment: P.S if I simply click the cygwin terminal icon, i will start a mintty.exe under platform "cygwin".

Comment: Are you sure you are running `python` from Cygwin? I am guessing that you are running a `python` built for Windows rather than Cygwin. That would show these results.

Comment: @JACKZHANG As Liturgist mentioned you should check your python with  `which python`. On my system the path isn't set when I started mintty via cmd.exe. But when I start it with `/usr/bin/python` I got `sys.platform=='cygwin'`

Comment: this really helps. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You may start a bash from the Windows terminal and start your script from there (without starting `mintty.exe`). Just execute

```
bash -c "cd /your/directory && python myPython.py"
```

from the Windows cmd prompt or a batch file.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Please see edited thanks!